# 2D vector treatment and visualisation

Tags: vector, visualization

I'm just trying to define a set of vectors, in the Cartesian plane, draw the vectors originating from the origin $O,$ and be able to add vectors and draw the resulting vector.

I've started doing this using the Arrow function, as follows:

```
v1 = {{0,0},{1,1}};
v2 = {{0,0},{1,2}};
```

and so on, then to create the diagram:

```
Graphics[{Arrow[v1],Arrow[v2],Arrow[v1+v2]},Axes-> True]
```

- Is this the proper way of doing vector visualizations and simple manipulations?
- How can one attribute different colors to e.g. the summed vector v1+v2? Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Have you seen `Graphics` documentation page?

Comment: @Kuba :( to be honest I mainly wanted to get informed on the chosen method (using arrows instead of potentially another more suited option). Sorry for the lack of effort from my end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track. You don't have to repeat `Arrow` everytime.

```
Graphics[{Arrow[{v1, v2}], Red, Arrow[v1 + v2]}, 
 Axes -> True, 
 GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also just tried adding a point to the same diagram using Point[], and put the vectors in a list and fed them to arrow using `Map[Arrow,vectorlist]` in graphics, and it worked. Neat!