# How can I plot a space time diagram in mathematica?

Tags: graphics, physics, homework

"Using Mathematica, construct space-time diagrams for which the speed of $S’$ moving in the positive x-direction with respect to $S$ and at speed $V$ with respect to $S$ for:

(a) $V=0.1c$;

(b) $V=0.4c$;

(c) $V=0.8c$ (on separate sheets).

Include gridlines for the $S’$ coordinate systems in each case."

These space-time diagrams look like this:

[image]

Where the black coordinate axis is the $S$ plane and the blue coordiante axis the $S'$ plane.

We just started special relativity and this was assigned. I know how to plot functions using Mathematica and thats about it. I do not want anyone to explicitly write the coding for me. If someone could maybe just tell me what functions to use, I will try learning those on my own and see what I can do with them.

Comment: Dear @Aalostad, does my answer suffice to get you on the way? If so it would be nice if you'd accept it; if not please explain why. That is: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the tour and check the faqs! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign!

Comment: Yes, it did help. I didn't know about the Graphics command or the Show command, which were both extremely helpful. I was able to finish the assignment, but probably not in the most efficient manner. Essentially what I did was plot everything as a line within the Show command. Then I added labels using the Graphics and Text command together. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/100341/29926) should already get you quite a way. I assume that you know how to label axes. You can use `Show` if you want to combine several graphical elements. Browse the examples in the documentation for more examples, and enjoy!