# Drawing several 2D vectors in one plot with labeled axes

Tags: graphics, vector

I want to draw vectors just with one plot. Also, I want to label the axes. Can anybody show me how can I do it?

Comment: For example, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100339/2d-vector-treatment-and-visualisation

Comment: What exactly do you need? At least show us a sketch or something.

Answer (score 1):

For 2D:

```
Graphics[Arrow /@ {{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {2, 1}}},
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

For 3D:

```
Graphics3D[Arrow /@ {{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 5}}},
 Axes -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```